# Memory issue reading a .csv file and allocating the data into a multi-dimensional array using C

Tags: arrays, c, csv, multidimensional-array

I should preface this by saying I have absolutely zero experience with C. However, I need to use it to write a UDF for a CFD simulation I'm doing.

My problem is that I have to read a .csv file and import those values to a 2d array so I can then access those values during the simulation. I have managed to get the code to read and print the data from the .csv file correctly. However, it all breaks when I try to convert and then add that data to an array.

I am using strtod() to convert the read data. It seems that this conversion works and gives correct values. However, when I add code to allocate it to the array, the code fails to read the whole .csv file, stopping about halfway through. I think this has to do with a memory issue (not sure though), hence why I tried to play around with pointers and the free() function. Although this doesn't seem to help at all. In fact, it just throws errors "attempt to free a non-heap object."

Could anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[128];
    int result;
    int width = 2;
    int csvlength = 224;
    double d;
    double data[csvlength][width];
    int counter=0;  // counter to move between fields

    FILE* f = fopen("vindisc.csv", "r");  // instantiate file object as pointer to allow for dynamic size.

    do {
        result = fscanf(f, "%127[^,\n]", str);  // get the result

        /* If it is end of line, skip */
        if(result == 0)
        {
            result = fscanf(f, "%*c");
        }

        /* otherwise, read in the data */
        else
        {
            if (counter%2 == 0) {
                printf("Field_1: %s\n", str);  
                d = strtod(str, NULL);
                //printf("Double test 1: %g\n", d);
                data[counter][0] = d;
            }
            else {
                printf("Field_2: %s\n", str);
                d = strtod(str, NULL);
                //printf("Double test 2: %g\n", d);
                data[counter][1] = d; 
            }
            
            counter++;  // update the counter
        }
        //free(&str);
    } while(result != EOF);  // close the file after the read.

    for(int i = 0; i < csvlength; i++) {
        printf("%g", data[i][0]);
        printf("\n");  
        printf("%g", data[i][1]);
        printf("\n");   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Added an extract from the csv file to show the structure.

[image]

Comment: `char* str[128];` ==> `char str[128];` ..the first defines an array of 128 uninitialized pointers; the second an uninitialized array capable of holding a 127-long string

Comment: If you try to open a file, you should check to ensure it was successful before proceeding further with file operations.